# Generate Javadoc for OSGi bundle

Tags: apache-camel, javadoc, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm newbie in OSGi world but I was able to do some Camel and OSGi bundles to do some tasks in a middleware. Everything I made since was a proof of concept, but now I want to refactor some part of my code and I start writing a OSGi bundle who will contain common functionalities shared among other OSGi bundles.

To make it clean, I decide to write comments and use javadoc to get sleek documentation, but I'm stuck with this error:

```
Error resolving version for plugin 
'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin' from the repositories
```

I was able to run javadoc for another Camel component;

We have a local repository with the dependency maven-javadoc-plugin in;

I add the dependency maven-javadoc-plugin to my project;

I'm running out of ideas why it doesn't work.

Maybe I'm wrong and I using OSGi bundle in a wrong way...

**UPDATE**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>uces OSGi Bundle</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Activator>org.test.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Export-Package>org.test</Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-for-felix</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- To include a shell:
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.gogo.shell</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
            -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                        <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                        <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to=""/>
                                    </pathconvert>
                                    <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="bundles">
                                        <path path="${plugins.jars}"/>
                                        <mapper>
                                            <chainedmapper>
                                                <flattenmapper/>
                                                <globmapper from="*" to="file:modules/*" casesensitive="no"/>
                                            </chainedmapper>
                                        </mapper>
                                    </pathconvert>
                                    <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/config.properties">
                                        <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${bundles} file:modules/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
                                        <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*"/>
                                    </propertyfile>
                                    <copy file="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}" tofile="${project.build.directory}/felix.jar"/>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-executable-jar</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/felix.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>run-on-felix</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.gogo.shell:0.6.1 useless from Maven since stdin is swallowed -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="vm.args" value=""/>
                            <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to=""/>
                            </pathconvert>
                            <makeurl property="urls" separator=" ">
                                <path path="${plugins.jars}"/>
                                <path location="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
                            </makeurl>
                            <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties">
                                <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${urls}"/>
                                <entry key="felix.auto.deploy.action" value="uninstall,install,update,start"/>
                                <entry key="org.osgi.framework.storage" value="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}felix-cache"/>
                                <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*"/>
                            </propertyfile>
                            <makeurl property="run.properties.url" file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties"/>
                            <java fork="true" jar="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}">
                                <sysproperty key="felix.config.properties" value="${run.properties.url}"/>
                                <jvmarg line="${vm.args}"/>
                            </java>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Could you please post your pom somewhere?

Comment: I update my post with the pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally found my response after digging more deeply in javadoc page ([Javadoc documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html)) and add these lines into the build section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
</plugin>
```